# Youtube-api v3: is it possible to get videos on a certain order?

Tags: android, youtube-api

i'm trying to get certain order from youtube videos on my Android application. I want to search, for example:

```
Fight 1
Fight 2
Fight 3
Fight 4
```

This is my search list:

```
YouTube.Search.List search = mYouTubeDataApi.search().list("id,snippet");

            search.setKey(ApiKey.YOUTUBE_API_KEY);
            search.setQ(mTitle + " " + mSearchQuery);

            search.setType("video");                
            search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
            search.setMaxResults(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS);
            searchResponse = search.execute();
```

So far, i've tried adding to my Search List:

```
search.setOrder("title");
```

and also i tried to sort manually the items this way

```
    List<Video> items = videoListResponse.getItems();
    Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<Video>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Video video, Video t1) {
            return video.getSnippet().getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(t1.getSnippet().getTitle());
        }
    });
    return new Pair(searchResponse.getNextPageToken(), items);
```

but i still don't get the results as i expect, and my sort is not good (i.e.: fight 1, fight 10, fight 11, fight 2, etc...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) using the HTTP request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search
```

with the optional parameter `order` added to the query.

As discussed in the documentation,

> The **order** parameter specifies the method that will be used to order resources in the API response.

Acceptable values are:

- **date** – sorted in reverse chronological order based on the date they were created.
- **rating** – sorted from highest to lowest rating.
- **relevance** – sorted based on their relevance to the search query. This is the default value for this parameter.
- **title** – sorted alphabetically by title.
- **videoCount** – Channels are sorted in descending order of their number of uploaded videos.
- **viewCount** – sorted from highest to lowest number of views. For live broadcasts, videos are sorted by number of concurrent viewers while the broadcasts are ongoing.

Comment: how can I use both ``date`` and ``rating`` at a time?

Comment: do note that the documentation says it costs 100 units.